# iAD best practices for shared AdBannerView's and animated transitions

Tags: objective-c, view, iad, shared, adbannerview

I have a global ADBannerView that I show on most of my top-level Views.  When each view loads, it does a -removeFromSuper on the adBanner, then adds it as a subview.

However, when animating from one top-level view to another, this causes the ad to suddenly disappear from the departing view before the transition starts.

I've tried using viewWillAppear/Disappear as well, but in each case, they don't seem to get called at an appropriate time to remove/add the banner.

I assume it's a very bad thing to have the ADBannerView's view belong to subviews on two different top-level Viewsat the same time.

The only other thing that comes to mind is animating away the ad before the transition occurs; another animation in the queue would be a bit of a pain, though, and seems like a misguided solution.

Is there any other reasonably simple and elegant way to share an ad banner between top-level Views where transitions are involved?